# Load classified data from CSV to Scikit-Learn for machine learning

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm learning Scikit-Learn to do some classifying for tweets. I have a csv with tweets on one column, and their class from 0-11 in next column. I went through [this tutorial from Scikit-Learn site](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#tutorial-setup) I think I understand how the actual classifying is done but I don't think I really understood the data format. In tutorial the material was in files in folders where folder names acted as a classification tag.

In my case I should load that data from csv file and apparently I need to construct the datastructure which is feed to vectorizer and classifier manually. How I should approach this? I think the tutorial was a bit ambiguous in this respect since the data loading was done automagically and left me in dark concerning the structure and loading of custom data.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `pandas` documentation. Especially `pandas.read_table` and `pandas.read_csv` might interest you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally you would use [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) or if you don't want a pandas dependency [numpy.load](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or even load the cvs to a list using the standard library. It would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', header=None, sep=',', 
                 names=['tweets', 'class'])   # columns names if no header
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(df['tweets']) 
y = df['class']
```

Once you have your `X` and `y` you can feed them to a classifier.

Comment: Thank you! Nice to see it was that simple after all. Should take a proper look into Pandas when I have time.