# Importing CSV data into scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have data stored in a CSV file as follows:

```
abv,ibu,label
6.1,60.0,American Pale Ale (APA)
9.9,92.0,American Barleywine
7.9,45.0,Winter Warmer
4.4,42.0,American Pale Ale (APA)`
```

My understanding is that it accepts data in a 2D array.

Comment: Import as a pandas dataframe using read_csv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load classified data from CSV to Scikit-Learn for machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675395/load-classified-data-from-csv-to-scikit-learn-for-machine-learning)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Before you use scikit-learn you need to one-hot encode the label.

```
y = pd.get_dummies(dat['label'])
X = dat[:2]
```

These are the general ideas, hope they help.